# Flexslider in Drupal 7 breaks JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, flexslider

I've been working with Flexslider in Drupal 7, but when I try to create a page with a slider, the JQuery on the entire page stops working.

```
flexslider.load.js?no0zdc:41 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
```

That's the error message that I receive. I've already uploaded the javascript library files provided by [WooThemes](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider) and I've checked to make sure that they have been uploaded to the correct folder (/sites/all/libraries/flexslider/).

I'm a bit stuck. My best guess is that there is a conflict in the way JQuery is being called on the page since JQuery works on every other page, so for reference, I have posted some code from my header below:

**EDIT**

Full header below:

```
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="Sample content" about="/sample-content" property="dc:title">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width">
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)">
<link rel="canonical" href="/sample-content">
<link rel="shortlink" href="/node/114">
  <title>Sample content | ILIAS Solutions</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_pbm0lsQQJ7A7WCCIMgxLho6mI_kBNgznNUWmTWcnfoE.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_IoEPASs8P-5r05g2SNWObjq4Z3L1qnpf6AUHzJOv_Mw.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css__OGyo-ZLPb2eWR69kov4bKl5fA7ngglWR1B1kbenDy4.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_MnXiytJtb186Ydycnpwpw34cuUsHaKc80ey5LiQXhSY.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_9vS7KTziVXM6cOtv0jZFlm30ZZXGCzz9d4oZYdJnbf4.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_X2KZyy7-i2nDSO3slgqaJQDJe_rcOgl-_DFA2q0nlLI.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/startupgrowth_lite/fonts/lato-font.css?no15n3" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/startupgrowth_lite/fonts/sourcecodepro-font.css?no15n3" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/startupgrowth_lite/fonts/ptserif-blockquote-font.css?no15n3" media="all">

<!--[if (IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/startupgrowth_lite/ie9.css?no15n3" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css_AbpHGcgLb-kRsJGnwFEktk7uzpZOCcBY74-YBdrKVGs.css" media="all">

  <!-- HTML5 element support for IE6-8 -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/drupal.js?no15n3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js?v=1.10.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/misc/1.9/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js?v=1.2.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/misc/1.9/overlay-parent.js?v=1.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.js?no15n3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu_toolbar/admin_menu_toolbar.js?no15n3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $("#toTop").addClass("show");   
            } else {
                $("#toTop").removeClass("show");
            }
        });

        $("#toTop").click(function() {
            $("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},800);
        }); 

        });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/startupgrowth_lite/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js?no15n3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

        $("#main-navigation ul.main-menu, #main-navigation .content>ul.menu").mobileMenu({
            prependTo: "#main-navigation",
            combine: false,
            nested: 1,
            switchWidth: 760,
            topOptionText: Drupal.settings.startupgrowth_lite['topoptiontext']
        });

        });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

        var map;
        var myLatlng;
        var myZoom;
        var marker;

        });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script><script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

        if ($("#map-canvas").length) {

            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Drupal.settings.startupgrowth['google_map_latitude'], Drupal.settings.startupgrowth['google_map_longitude']);
            myZoom = 13;

            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                zoom: myZoom,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: myLatlng,
                scrollwheel: false
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(Drupal.settings.startupgrowth['google_map_canvas']),mapOptions);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                draggable:true,
                position: myLatlng,
                url: "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//40.726576,-74.046822/@40.726576,-74.046822"
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {     
                window.open(this.url, "_blank");
                });

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                map.setCenter(myLatlng);
                });

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

        }

        });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

            var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
            $(window).scroll(function() {
            if(($(this).scrollTop() > headerHeight) && ($(window).width() > 767)) {
                $("body").addClass("onscroll"); 
                $("body").css("paddingTop", (headerHeight)+"px");
                if( $(this).scrollTop() > headerHeight+40 ) {
                $("body").addClass("show"); 
                }
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("onscroll");
                $("body").removeClass("show");
                $("body").css("paddingTop", (0)+"px");
                $("body.logged-in").css("paddingTop", (64)+"px");
            }
            });
        });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/startupgrowth_lite/js/meanmenu/jquery.meanmenu.min.js?no15n3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $("#main-navigation .sf-menu, #main-navigation .content>ul.menu, #main-navigation ul.main-menu").wrap("<div class='meanmenu-wrapper'></div>");
            $("#main-navigation .meanmenu-wrapper").meanmenu({
                meanScreenWidth: "767",
                meanRemoveAttrs: true,
                meanMenuContainer: "#header-inside",
                meanMenuClose: ""
            });

        });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $(window).load(function() {
                $("#highlighted-bottom-transparent-bg").css("backgroundColor", "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)");
            });

        });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/startupgrowth_lite/js/jquery.browser.min.js?no15n3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\u002F", "pathPrefix":"", "ajaxPageState":{"theme":"startupgrowth_lite", "theme_token":"Cv8zpIqC1NrJFXXv3ef0_APXlwgYfd8ijffT8WgyKoc", "js":{"sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fflexslider\u002Fassets\u002Fjs\u002Fflexslider.load.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fjquery_update\u002Freplace\u002Fjquery\u002F1.10\u002Fjquery.min.js":1, "misc\u002Fjquery.once.js":1, "misc\u002Fdrupal.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fjquery_update\u002Freplace\u002Fui\u002Fui\u002Fminified\u002Fjquery.ui.core.min.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fjquery_update\u002Freplace\u002Fmisc\u002F1.9\u002Fjquery.ba-bbq.min.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fjquery_update\u002Freplace\u002Fmisc\u002F1.9\u002Foverlay-parent.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fadmin_menu\u002Fadmin_menu.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fadmin_menu\u002Fadmin_menu_toolbar\u002Fadmin_menu_toolbar.js":1, "\u002F\u002Fmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\u002Fbootstrap\u002F3.3.2\u002Fjs\u002Fbootstrap.min.js":1, "0":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Fjs\u002Fjquery.mobilemenu.js":1, "1":1, "2":1, "https:\u002F\u002Fmaps.googleapis.com\u002Fmaps\u002Fapi\u002Fjs?v=3.exp\u0026sensor=false":1, "3":1, "4":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Fjs\u002Fmeanmenu\u002Fjquery.meanmenu.min.js":1, "5":1, "6":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Fjs\u002Fjquery.browser.min.js":1}, "css":{"modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.base.css":1, "modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.menus.css":1, "modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.messages.css":1, "modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.theme.css":1, "misc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.core.css":1, "misc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.theme.css":1, "modules\u002Foverlay\u002Foverlay-parent.css":1, "modules\u002Ffield\u002Ftheme\u002Ffield.css":1, "modules\u002Fnode\u002Fnode.css":1, "modules\u002Fsearch\u002Fsearch.css":1, "modules\u002Fuser\u002Fuser.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fviews\u002Fcss\u002Fviews.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fadmin_menu\u002Fadmin_menu.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fadmin_menu\u002Fadmin_menu_toolbar\u002Fadmin_menu_toolbar.css":1, "modules\u002Fshortcut\u002Fshortcut.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fctools\u002Fcss\u002Fctools.css":1, "\u002F\u002Fmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\u002Ffont-awesome\u002F4.2.0\u002Fcss\u002Ffont-awesome.min.css":1, "\u002F\u002Fmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\u002Fbootstrap\u002F3.3.2\u002Fcss\u002Fbootstrap.min.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Fjs\u002Fmeanmenu\u002Fmeanmenu.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Fstyle.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Ffonts\u002Flato-font.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Ffonts\u002Fsourcecodepro-font.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Ffonts\u002Fptserif-blockquote-font.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Fie9.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstartupgrowth_lite\u002Flocal.css":1}}, "overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Frevert\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u002F*\u000Aoverlay\u002Fdismiss-message\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fshortcuts\u000Aadmin\u000Aadmin\u002F*\u000Abatch\u000Ataxonomy\u002Fterm\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fcancel\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u002F*", "non_admin":"admin\u002Fstructure\u002Fblock\u002Fdemo\u002F*\u000Aadmin\u002Freports\u002Fstatus\u002Fphp"}, "pathPrefixes":[  ], "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"}, "flexslider":{"optionsets":{"flexslider_default_thumbnail_slider":{"namespace":"flex-", "selector":".slides \u003E li", "easing":"swing", "direction":"horizontal", "reverse":false, "smoothHeight":true, "startAt":0, "animationSpeed":600, "initDelay":0, "useCSS":true, "touch":true, "video":false, "keyboard":true, "multipleKeyboard":false, "mousewheel":0, "controlsContainer":".flex-control-nav-container", "sync":"", "asNavFor":"#flexslider-1", "itemWidth":210, "itemMargin":5, "minItems":0, "maxItems":0, "move":0, "animation":"slide", "slideshow":false, "slideshowSpeed":"7000", "directionNav":true, "controlNav":false, "prevText":"Previous", "nextText":"Next", "pausePlay":false, "pauseText":"Pause", "playText":"Play", "randomize":false, "animationLoop":false, "pauseOnAction":true, "pauseOnHover":false, "manualControls":""}}, "instances":{"flexslider-1":"flexslider_default_thumbnail_slider"}}, "startupgrowth_lite":{"topoptiontext":"Select a page", "google_map_latitude":"40.726576", "google_map_longitude":"-74.046822", "google_map_canvas":"map-canvas"}, "admin_menu":{"destination":"destination=node\u002F114", "hash":"37d586808ca3270fdd2a560149caab90", "basePath":"\u002Fadmin_menu", "replacements":{".admin-menu-users a":"0 \u002F 1"}, "margin_top":1, "toolbar":[  ]}});
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/util.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/10/stats.js"></script></head>
```

I hope I've provided sufficient information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at your status report 

Should give you 
"FlexSlider FlexSlider library installed.
Version 2.4 installed" if you installed the library correct (i think you did if i read your question)

Comment: Yep, I've checked it and it says that I've installed the Library correctly.

Comment: Looks to me like you're not loading the flexslider library. Have you checked it's in your page (it's not in the snippet you've posted above)?

Comment: Ah you bring up a good point. I'll post my full header. I do believe my header is loading the Flexslider library but I may be overlooking something.

Comment: I would have expected to see a line of the form: <script async="" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.2.2/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"> somewhere in there (I use a cdn). I don't think the library is being loaded.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised! I added the line that you wrote and it didn't change much. Any page that I try to add the slider to just ends up with a list of images instead.

Comment: The header that you posted is from a page that has a content type with the flexslider in it? Modules can load js files just where they need it

You should not add the cdn as you downloaded the library and added it to your sites/all

Also just in case try to clear cache if you did not already did that.

You should have the line
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://drupal7.dev/sites/all/libraries/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js?no1b2g"></script>
In pages where you are using the flexslider module.